# python Django - redirect to specific page after login required

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have audio-server in python -Django.
I have scenario that I am send a link to admin via E-mail to approve login credentials. link will contain tokan genre-ted by tokan generator something like http://domain/approve/MzA/69s-7a603f32c695968a5345/
I want view function to give list of all users who is on waiting list.
but when admin comes on this link I want to check @login that user is logined in with admin credentials if yes redirect to http://domain/approve/MzA/69s-7a603f32c695968a5345/ page else "sorry-page".
I have @user_passes_test(is_mbcadmin,login_url="/login/") before my view def but it is redirect to  dashboard after right credentials login.

can anyone help?
PB

Comment: In your settings.py define LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL . It will take the name of the url to which you want to redirect after login. urlpatterns = [ "home/" , views.homePage , name = "home-page") ] .  in settings.py LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home-page"

Comment: I don't want user to redirect default page which is define in settings.py. I want to redirect user to next?=... variable in link.

Comment: You can do this in your views , you just get the next variable from your get request , next = request.GET.get("next") , you will get the next page name or the url , just redirect it to that page . You want the code,  just say it .

Comment: yes please, if you can provide me code because next = request.GET.get("next")  in view not working for me.